# How to create read/write .txt file in xcode4?

Tags: ios

i am newbie of iOS development , i'm facing a problem from last 2 days 
I want to create , read and write .txt file in xcode4 ... please help me as a complete code.
your answer accepted warmly.
Thanks.

Comment: Firstly Xcode is the development IDE; did mean "how to create read/write .txt file in iOS?", perhaps?  Secondly there are numerous examples of doing file I/O on this site and the internet in general, so please search.

Comment: and also from February 1, you will not be able to submit binaries build with other than Xcode5 : https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each iOS app you can only write file inside app's document directory. 
Here is a sample code to do that.

```
//ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
@public

    NSString *filePath;
    NSString *fileData;    
    IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *filePath;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *fileData;
@end





//ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize filePath;
@synthesize fileData;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0]];

    //define a file path
    filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourFile.txt"]];    

    //check if file is exists or not then write some data
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        fileData = @"My name is maverick";
        [fileData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:nil];
        textView.text = fileData;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)readFile:(id)sender
{
    fileData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath usedEncoding:nil error:nil];
    textView.text = fileData;
}

-(IBAction)writeFile:(id)sender
{
    fileData = textView.text;
    [fileData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try if not created then i'll connect u later.

Comment: sorry ! i try but fail to implement it , plz help me.

Comment: Where you failed to implement? can you please tell in details?

Comment: char *saves = "abcd";
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:saves length:4];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile"];
    [data writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];

Comment: to write in .txt file                                                   
        paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
        (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        
        fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/textfile.txt", documentsDirectory];
        content = @"One\nTwo\nThree\nFour\nFive";
    [content writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];